# How to select two and three check box in a table

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

How to select random checkbox in a table because checkbox id, type , name are  same then how to get random checkbox select and value is different.
http://prntscr.com/106nuzd

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.id("#checkbox"));
    a.get(new Random().nextInt(a.size())).click();
```

**use findElements to get all checkbox and then use Random to generate a random index and click on that webelement in the list**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to select random number of checkboxes,

```
List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.id("#checkbox"));
Random rand = new Random(); //instance of random class
int int_random = rand.nextInt(a.size()); 
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i += int_random) {
    a.get(i).click();
}
```

This will iterate through the list of all checkboxes with ID="checkbox" and then randomly increment the counter so that the loop doesn't go sequentially selecting all the checkboxes.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment ,

Comment: Thanks for the help